# MS SQL Linked Server to MariaDB (Mysql) wont work with readonly mariadb user

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb, linked-server

We have scenario where our MS SQL access data on a MariaDB (Mysql) database through a Linked Server.

That has been working fine so far, but we now need to limit the user that's being used by the Linked Server configuration so it's readonly. We created a user with read only access, but when changing the connection details on the Linked Server it won't work anymore. It can't even connect to the openquery, saying the user / password arent correct.

Do you know if there's a work around for this? Linked Server configuration will only work with users that have full access to the mysql DB, and we need to restrict that access.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Linked Server rather than dblink? AFAIK (and according to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dblink/info)) dblink is an Oracle/PostgreSQL thing, not related to SQL Server or MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: Hi Adyson, thans for clarifying that and I'm sorry for using the wrong term. I meant Liked Server . We just refered to it as a Dblink :-/ I just edited the post